# $\lim_{x\to a+}f(x)=-\infty$ therefore $\lim_{x\to a+}f'(x)=\infty$?

Tags: calculus

Does $\lim_{x\to a+}f(x)=-\infty$ imply that $\lim_{x\to a+}f'(x)=\infty$?

Really sorry about the awful formatting. I've added an example for a function that satisfies the conditions. (Graph below.) I'm a freshman in bio-medical engineering, so if what I'm saying isn't even correct, do please let me know!

[image: Graph]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: For *your* function it holds. It does *not* need to hold in general - you may want to make up a pathological function that will make up, sort of, a wavy "staircase", going to $-\infty$ as $x\to a+$ but for shorter and shorter intervals going horizontally - and so there will be points as close as you want to $a$ such that the derivative is zero. The best you can prove is that $\lim\sup_{x\to a+}f'(x)=+\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is chosen so that it is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f'$ is uniformly continuous (that is to say for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $\delta>0$ so that if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f'(x)-f'(y)|<\epsilon$ then this holds true. It is also true if $f'$ is monotonic.

In fact it is easy to see that if as long as $f'$ exists and it is bounded from above (so $f'\leq C$) then $\liminf_{x\to a}f(x)$ is bounded from below:
We get for any $x,\epsilon$ that for $|h|$ sufficiently small we have
$$ \frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h} < C+\epsilon $$
This implies $f(x-h) > f(x)-(C+\epsilon)h$.

Now fix some $r\in(a,b)$ and take $l$ infimal so that $f(x)\geq f(r)-(C+\epsilon)(r-x)$ for all $x\in(l,r)$. Then by limiting we get
$$ f(l) \geq f(r) - (C+\epsilon)(r-l) $$
Suppose $l\neq a$. Then we can find an $\rho>0$ so that for $|h|<\rho$ we get
$$ f(l-h) > f(l)-(C+\epsilon)h > f(r) - (C+\epsilon)(h+r-l) = f(r) - (C+\epsilon)(r-(l-h))$$
which contradicts the infimality of $l$.

But thus $f$ is bounded towards $a$ from below by $f(r)-(C+\epsilon)(r-a)$.

So by contraposition if $f$ limits to $-\infty$ it is not bounded from below and thus $f'$ cannot be bounded from above. But this only means that there exists **one** sequence $x_n\to a$ so that $f'(x_n)\to\infty$.

If $f'$ is uniformly continuous this is sufficient to say that any sequence $a_n\to a$ satisfies this (as if $|x_n-a|<\delta$ and $|y_n-a|<\delta$ (which is true for $n$ sufficiently large) we get $|x_n-y_n|<\delta$, and thus $f'(y_n)>f'(x_n)-\epsilon$). As you can see we do not in fact need uniformly continuous here, it it sufficient if at least for *one* $\epsilon>0$ there is such a $\delta>0$.

Similarly this holds true for $f'$ monotonic close to $a$.

If this condition does not hold it might be that $f'$ does not in fact take a limit (in some sense). For example:

https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFjUEKwjAQAO-F_iG3bmy0iVBv8SMiEkyiC20NSYT19268eJ0ZGB-BpIWCG5iJ5GjkRH2XllcFH5U-GGVk37lS3muA44725qwZRGEFbjU8squhlcTtrIhVyixgwRUrMLdaecx2GAfJkvv0xHu5uZzdBy6_Ufto3U5K_M_6xOAqv3hPLgM=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.

For example, if
$$
f(x)=-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
then
$$
f'(x)=\frac{2}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
-\frac{1}{x^3}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
Clearly $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=-\infty$.

Meanwhile, for $x_n=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$, we have that $x_n\to 0$, $x_n>0$ and
$$
f'(x_n)=\frac{2-\sin(1/x_n)}{x_n^2}-\frac{\cos(1/x_n)}{x_n^3}\\ =
4\pi^2 n^2\big(2-\sin(2\pi n)\big)-8\pi^3 n^3\cos(2\pi n)=
8\pi^2 n^2-8\pi^3 n^3\to -\infty
$$